# How to detect Openwrt kern.info and daemon.info events?

Tags: linux, event-handling, syslog, openwrt

My background is mostly Windows programming in C and C++. Recently I've had the chance to work with some embedded Linux systems also, but I'm still new at this.

Right now I'm working on a utility for Openwrt that needs to react to network and system events that occur during normal operation.

I've been able to use Hotplug for some events, but others still elude me. I can parse the output of the system log using logread, but that seems primitive and hackish.

In particular I'd like to get a callback similar to what hotplug does for some of the 'kern.info kernel' and 'daemon.info' events.  For example:

```
 Mar 31 19:42:32 OpenWrt kern.info kernel: [  369.540000] device wlan0 left promiscuous mode
    Mar 31 19:42:32 OpenWrt kern.info kernel: [  369.540000] br-lan: port 2(wlan0) entered disabled state
    Mar 31 19:42:32 OpenWrt kern.info kernel: [  369.730000] device wlan1 left promiscuous mode
    Mar 31 19:42:32 OpenWrt kern.info kernel: [  369.730000] br-lan: port 3(wlan1) entered disabled state
    Mar 31 19:42:34 OpenWrt kern.info kernel: [  371.360000] device wlan0 entered promiscuous mode


Mar 31 19:45:56 OpenWrt daemon.info hostapd: wlan0: STA 04:f7:e4:00:00:00 IEEE 802.11: authenticated
    Mar 31 19:45:56 OpenWrt daemon.info hostapd: wlan0: STA 04:f7:e4:00:00:00 IEEE 802.11: associated (aid 1)
    Mar 31 19:45:56 OpenWrt daemon.info hostapd: wlan0: STA 04:f7:e4:00:00:00 WPA: pairwise key handshake completed (WPA)
    Mar 31 19:45:56 OpenWrt daemon.info hostapd: wlan0: STA 04:f7:e4:00:00:00 WPA: group key handshake completed (WPA)
    Mar 31 19:45:56 OpenWrt daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[5005]: DHCPREQUEST(br-lan) 10.1.1.51 04:f7:e4:00:00:00
    Mar 31 19:45:56 OpenWrt daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[5005]: DHCPNAK(br-lan) 10.1.1.51 04:f7:e4:00:00:00 wrong network
    Mar 31 19:46:00 OpenWrt daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[5005]: DHCPDISCOVER(br-lan) 04:f7:e4:00:00:00
    Mar 31 19:46:00 OpenWrt daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[5005]: DHCPOFFER(br-lan) 192.168.1.198 04:f7:e4:1c:09:00
    Mar 31 19:46:00 OpenWrt daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[5005]: DHCPDISCOVER(br-lan) 04:f7:e4:1c:09:00
    Mar 31 19:46:00 OpenWrt daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[5005]: DHCPOFFER(br-lan) 192.168.1.198 04:f7:e4:1c:09:00
    Mar 31 19:46:01 OpenWrt daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[5005]: DHCPREQUEST(br-lan) 192.168.1.198 04:f7:e4:1c:09:00
    Mar 31 19:46:01 OpenWrt daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[5005]: DHCPACK(br-lan) 192.168.1.198 04:f7:e4:1c:09:00 My-iPhone
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Log entries like the `DHCPOFFER` (as seen in your example) are generated individually by the corresponding process (for example, by `udhcpc`) using the Unix [syslog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syslog) mechanism (kind-of like the Windows Event Logging API)

By default on OpenWRT logging is handled by the `syslogd` process provided by the `busybox` package.  This is fairly primitive and simply sends messages to the circular buffer you see using `logread` and/or to a UDP socket.

You can upgrade logging on OpenWRT to use the `syslog-ng` package.  This has a much more advanced configuration and you should be able to use this to send filtered log events to a script that you can  write to do what you need with them.

```
opkg install syslog-ng
```

syslog-ng is a GPL product but the documentation is now buried beneath a commercial web site, one would hope you can get it from the source code , via http://freecode.com/projects/syslog-ng.  Note that OpenWRT seems to provide version 1.6.12 which I had trouble finding the documentation for when I implemented it on my OpenWRT devices, but eventually I found it via the wayback machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20070406054439/http://www.balabit.com/products/syslog_ng/reference-1.6/syslog-ng.html/x731.html (for example)

A configuration file fragment that would pull out those DHCP messages and send them to a standalone log file would look a bit like:

```
source src { unix-stream("/dev/log"); internal(); };
destination dhcp_messages { file("/var/log/dhcpmessages"); };
filter f_dhcp { match("dnsmasq-dhcp"); };
log {
    source(src);
    filter(f_dhcp);
    destination(dhcp_messages);
};
```

You might probably find the `pipe()` or `program()` destination drivers the most useful for your application. For example, using a `program()` driver you could send selected messages to a shell script that parses them and saves them into a sqlite database.